# VB.NET Regex Replacement

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a list of fields named flav*x*(other text) that go 1 through 10.
For example, I might have:

```
flav2PGPct
```

I need to turn it to

```
flav12PGPct
```

I need to replaced `1` through `10` with `11` through `20` using VB.NET's `Replace` function with Regex, but I can't get it working right.

Can anyone help?

Here's what I've tried:

```
(\.)flav*[1-9]
```

I have no idea what to place in the replacement box...

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear guys, I'm not using this in Code, but in the Search and Replace box in Visual Studio to actually replace code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex for search: `(flav)(\d\w*)` and this one for replace: `${1}1$2`.

Comment: It won't match 10, since `\d` will only match a single digit.

Comment: I can work around it, unless you have another solution?

Comment: Not really. Since you're doing it in the IDE, I would just say, manually replace that last case. Substitution regexes don't have very good If/then mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use 2 regex runs to obtain the desired result because it is not possible to use a replacement literal with alternatives.

The first regex would replace `10` to `20` and the second will handle 1 to 9 digits:

```
Dim rx1to9 As Regex = New Regex("(?<=\D|^)[1-9](?=\D|$)") '1 - 9
Dim rx10 As Regex = New Regex("(?<=\D|^)10(?=\D|$)") '10
Dim str As String = "flav2PG10Pct101"
Dim result = rx10.Replace(str, "20")
result = rx1to9.Replace(result, "1$&")
Console.WriteLine(result)
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/yMZUeJ) (output is `flav12PG20Pct101`)

**Regex explanation**:

- `(?<=\D|^)` - A positive look-behind that makes sure there is no digit (`\D`) or start of string (`^`) before...
- `[1-9]` - a single digit from `1` to `9` (or, in the second regex, `10` matching literal `10`)
- `(?=\D|$)` - A positive look-ahead that makes sure there is no digit (`\D`) or the end of string (`$`) after the digit.

If you must check if `flav` is present in the string, you may use a bit different look-behind: `(?<=flav\D*|^)`, or - if spaces should not occur between `flav` and the digit: `(?<=flav[^\d\s]*|^)`.

Answer (score 0):

Regexes work best with strings rather than numbers, so an easy way is to use a regex to get the parts of the string you want to adjust and then concatenate the calculated part in a string:

```
Option Strict On
Option Infer On

Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim re As New Regex("^flav([0-9]+)(.*)$")
        Dim s = "flav1PGPct"
        Dim t = ""
        Dim m = re.Match(s)
        If m.Success Then
            t = CStr(Integer.Parse(m.Groups(1).Value) + 10)
            t = "flav" & t & m.Groups(2).Value
        End If
        Console.WriteLine(t)

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```